# Error while CAPTCHA after Login

Tags: bug

I got an error after I logged in.

I pressed the CAPTCHA checkbox and after a loading time of around 30 seconds I got an error message.

I had to log in again after I got linked to this site: [CAPTCHA ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/nocaptcha).

Comment: Couple of suggestions: 1)capitalize your 'I's. 2) no need for a signature at the end of a post. This is pure fluff and should be removed. (Both here and on the main site btw :) )